# How to pass a membervariable as variable itself

Tags: c++, class, member, void

Imagine you have a class with 100 or more member variables:

```
class DataContainer { int a1; int a2; ... double a100; };
```

and another class which accesses and analysis parts of the variables in the first class:

```
class Analysis {
  protected:  
  DataContainer *myData;
  void myVar1, myVar2;

  public:
  Analysis() {...}
  void myChoice(void a, void b) { myVar1 = a; myVar2 = b }
  void Analyse(DataContainer data) { 
    myData = data; 
    /* do something with myVar1 and myVar2 */
  }
};
```

but before analysing you have to choose which parameters to use. I would like to know how to write a call for this myChoice-function which is not simply passing the content of a variable, but the choice of the membervariable itself.

In order to ask more generally: I think the position in the memory of a class-member relatively to the class itself is fixed (is it?) Independet if it is a new instance of that class or not. So how can I tell the combiler "Please use the membervariable a3 always". Instead of the content of a3.

Comment: `100` member variables? are you kidding me? What happened to using arrays?

Comment: My underlying program is much more complex, I tried to keep the example easy. It is a generic data-structure with different datatype, therefore no Arrays.... :-(

Comment: It is a very bad idea to try and access member variables through a pointer to the class.  There is a little thing called padding that will get in your way.

Comment: The question is basically if I can refence to a member variable by doing ( size_t(oneClassInstance)-size_t(&oneClassMember) ). Will this work to find the classmember a later instance?

Comment: Sounds to me like there *has* to be better ways to solve whatever problem it is you are trying to solve with this.

Comment: A few ideas - make DataContainer map<string,string> and treat the fields as name-value pairs.  Parse the data out of the strings later, or make it a map<string, complex-field-type>.  Or make Analysis a virtual base, with a separate class for each type of analysis, so that class knows how to read specific hard coded fields from DataContainer.

Comment: @Georg yes it will "work" that way, it is just ugly way to re-implement of what is already implemented through pointer to member. And if you really need it you should use `std::offsetof` instead of hacks with `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: I don't get the high number of down votes on this question. It seems mostly OK to me.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because the question introduces a broad problem, then asks specific details of a potentially bad approach, and it's hard to tell what the actual goal is. The key seems to be how do you select the parts to analyze? Are they specific to different types of analysis, or do we need to be able to pick arbitrary elements out of DataContainer for a nearly infinite set of analysis runs?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [pointers-to-data-members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) are for.

```
int    DataContainer::* myVar1 = &DataContainer::a1;
double DataContainer::* myVar2 = &DataContainer::a100;
```

> I think the position in the memory of a class-member relatively to the class itself is fixed (is it?)

It is indeed. The relative position does not change at run time. This is why pointers-to-data-members work. They can be implemented as a memory offset.

PS. Considering how massive `DataContainer` is, I would not recommend passing it by value if you can avoid it.

PPS. Consider grouping the member variables into sub-structures.

Comment: hm.... I do not think so... Image after the "choice" the class-instance is deleted and then a new is passed to be analysed, the pointers will differ

Comment: ok, great, that means for my case, that I can simply calculate ( size_t(originalClass) - size_t(&selectedMember) + size_t(newClassInstance) ) in order to find the pointer to that member in the new class

Comment: sorry vice-versa "member-class+class"

Comment: @Georg `the pointers will differ` The position of the member relative to the container object is always the same. `for my case, that I can simply calculate ...` No need to calculate anything. The compiler does the calculation for you when you use pointers-to-data-members. But your proposed calculation is rather strange. We aren't talking about several classes here, are we? Just different instances of the class `DataContainer`.

Comment: @Georg you are wrong, you cannot use pointer to member without pointer to a class instance, so this will work fine of course.

Comment: How do you get from void myChoice(void a, void b) { myVar1 = a; myVar2 = b } to pointers-to-data-members?  Georg has to be able to represent the selection before you can make a pointer to it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom you replace the "`void`" arguments with pointers-to-data-members. Those pointers are what the caller uses to represent the selection.

Comment: Okay, that works, but doesn't that mean they are all known at compile time. It seems easier to just use data.a27 (for example) in the code. You would probably have something like public SelectMethodA(), public SelectMethodB(), etc, and they all call a private myChoice with their specific pointers-to-data-members?

Comment: @KennyOstrom the selection doesn't have to be known at compile time. You can do for example: `int DataContainer::* myVar1 = run_time_expression() ? &DataContainer::a1 : &DataContainer::a2`. I don't quite understand what you suggest by the `SelectMethodA`, but whoever calls `myChoice` can pass a pointer of their choice, and that choice can be made at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to have a way to select specific fields in known ways, based on the type of analysis you are doing, then make Analyze virtual pure, and have specific types of analysis pick their fields directly.

From the question, I get the idea that you want to perform the same underlying computation, but use different data points based on the myChoice.

So the whole issue is how do you create the selection metadata? If there are a few specific, well documented ways to do it, then providing each in a subclass will be a very clear, concise and maintainable approach.

```
class Analysis {
public:
    virtual void Analyze(const DataContainer &data) = 0;
    virtual ~Analysis();
protected:
    void special_computation(int x, int y, double z);
};

class SpecificKindOfAnalysis : public Analysis {
public:
    void Analyze(const DataContainer &data){
        int x = data.a27;
        int y = data.a12;
        double z = data.a99;
        special_computation(x,y,z);
    }
};
```

This actually looks pretty horrible with variable names like x = data.a27, but I assume we're trying to be general here, and the actual program has meaningful names.